# sum up multilple datediffs of datetimes in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table with one user and one day's worth of punches (clockin, breakout, breakin, clockout).  Now say the user takes 2 or more breaks.  I need to sum up the total time of all breaks taken.  I have created a sqlfiddle to make it easier to show what I am trying to do.  Here is my example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/21542/6  Now I need to take (12:30:21 - 12:04:44) + (12:36:00 - 12:34:00) to get the total of all breaks taken.  How can I do that in my query.  Now pretend I have 10 users and 10 days in my table.  I would need to group by day and user I know.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by finding some way to link the punch-out records with the punch-in records from the same table. We can then put this data into a table and use it for querying against.

```
CREATE TEMPOARY TABLE breakPunchInOut ( 
    SELECT 
        DATE(punchout.PunchDateTime) AS ShiftDate,
        punchout.EmpId, 
        punchout.PunchId AS PunchOutID, 
        (SELECT 
            PunchId 
        FROM
            timeclock
        WHERE
            timeclock.EmpId = punchout.EmpId
        AND
            timeclock.`In-Out` = 1
        AND
            timeclock.PunchDateTime > punchout.PunchDateTime 
        AND
            DATE(timeclock.PunchDateTime) = DATE(punchout.PunchDateTime)
        ORDER BY
            timeclock.PunchDateTime ASC
        LIMIT 1
        ) AS PunchInID
    FROM
        timeclock AS punchout
    WHERE
        punchout.`In-Out` = 0
    HAVING
        PunchInID IS NOT NULL

);
```

The way this query works is looking for all the "punch-outs" in a specific day, for each of these it then looks for the next "punch-in" which happened on the same day, by the same person. The HAVING clause filters out records where there is no punch-in after a punch-out - so maybe where the employee goes home for the day. This is something to remember because if someone goes home halfway through a shift then their break time will not be added to the total.

It's important to point out that this approach will only work for shifts which start and end on the same day. If you have a night shift which starts in the evening and finishes in the morning the next day, then you'll have to alter the way that you join the punch outs and punch ins together.

Now that we have this linking table, its relatively simple to use it to create a summary report for each employee and each shift:

```
SELECT
    breakPunchInOut.ShiftDate,
    breakPunchInOut.EmpId,
    SUM(
      TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, punchOut.PunchDateTime, punchIn.PunchDateTime)
    ) AS TotalBreakLengthMins   
FROM
    breakPunchInOut
INNER JOIN
    timeclock AS punchOut
ON
    punchOut.PunchId = breakPunchInOut.PunchOutId
INNER JOIN
    timeclock AS punchIn
ON
    punchIn.PunchId = breakPunchInOut.PunchInId
GROUP BY
    breakPunchInOut.ShiftDate,
    breakPunchInOut.EmpId
;
```

Notice we use the TIMESTAMPDIFF function, not the DATEDIFF. DATEDIFF only calculates the number of days between two dates - it's not used for time.

Comment: This might work, I'm working on verifying the data, I'll mark as answer if it produces the correct results for me.

Comment: Ok, let me know if you have any problems - the TEMPORARY table won't work on sqlfiddle just remove that keyword and add it to the schema part.

Comment: If you want it as one bit of SQL then you can just insert the code for the temp table into the select like in this fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dd84d2/1